# Reading data from Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am trying to read data which I have received from a JSON object in the following format:

```
  var series = [{"Data":{"ArrayData":null,"DoubleArrayData":["\/Date(1481846400090)\/",1,"\/Date(1481846400100)\/",1,"\/Date(1481846400110)\/",1,"\/Date(1481846400120)\/",1],"Points":null,"SeriesData":null}, {"Data": ... }, {"Data": ... }];
```

I have tried doing the following in order to read the Data in the "DoubleArrayData" field:

```
 var ns = series[0].Data[1].DoubleArrayData[0];
```

However it returns undifined. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: series[0].Data.DoubleArrayData[0]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: `Data` is not an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your json object , `Data` is Object not an Array

```
var ns = series[0].Data.DoubleArrayData[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

`Data` is not an array, so you should access it's properties directly `series[0].Data.DoubleArrayData[0]`

```js
var series = [{
  "Data": {
    "ArrayData": null,
    "DoubleArrayData": ["\/Date(1481846400090)\/", 1, "\/Date(1481846400100)\/", 1, "\/Date(1481846400110)\/", 1, "\/Date(1481846400120)\/", 1],
    "Points": null,
    "SeriesData": null
  }
}];

console.log(series[0].Data.DoubleArrayData[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to add `[0]` to `Data` as it is an Object property, not an array:

```
series[0].Data.DoubleArrayData[0]
// Returns "/Date(1481846400090)/"
```

Answer (score 1):

`Data` is **not** an array, you don't have to use `[1]` (it should be used on array to get the index):

```
var ns = series[0].Data.DoubleArrayData[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not accessing the json object correctly.

**Your example json object:**

```
var series = [{"Data":{"ArrayData":null,"DoubleArrayData":["\/Date(1481846400090)\/",1,"\/Date(1481846400100)\/",1,"\/Date(1481846400110)\/",1,"\/Date(1481846400120)\/",1],"Points":null,"SeriesData":null}}];
```

**To access "DoubleArrayData field**

```
var ns = series[0]['Data']['DoubleArrayData']
```